# how to update python extension on visual studios code

Tags: python

Im a totally new to coding and I been starting with python and using visual studios. The problem is that recently I been getting a message that I need to update python to the latest version. I don't have any idea on how to update python on visual studios. can somebody help me out?
the program Im using is Visual studio code

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7500c.png)

Comment: Can you please add the message you are getting? A picture would also help.

Comment: Visual Studio or VS Code? Whichever it is, add specific version. Also, add exact error message.

Comment: I added a photo to the post.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+P, search Extensions Install, select Python. Go

Answer (score 0):

Click this icon:

[image: Extension Icon]

and you should see a list of extensions. Look for Python, and install/update as necessary.